# PHP timezone conflict

Tags: php, timezone

I have set my date.timezone setting in my php.ini directory as follows

```
date.timezone = "Asia/Kolkata"
```

When I run mktime using following parameters

```
mktime(0,0,0,10,11,1993);
```

The timestamp i get is 752907600

But when i precede the mktime function with date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
it gives me the expected output timestamp i.e. 752869800

If both the timezones are same then why is the output different?

----------------EDIT--------------------------

Ok I got the problem, but I dont know why is it occuring

```
echo date_default_timezone_get().'<br />';
echo mktime(0,0,0,11,10,1993).'<br />';
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
echo date_default_timezone_get().'<br />';
echo mktime(0,0,0,11,10,1993);
```

output

```
EST5EDT
752907600
Asia/Kolkata
752869800
```

I have set the .ini settings correctly then what may be the problem?

Comment: Put `echo date_default_timezone_get()` at the top of your page and make sure you get the value you expect

Comment: Are you sure it's the correct `php.ini`?

Comment: did you restart your server after changed in php.ini?

Comment: do you perhaps use windows with WAMP or XAMPP installation? In that case you may have 2 or even 3 `php.ini` laying around. XAMPP uses `\xampp\php\php.ini` and WAMP uses `\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.X\bin\php.ini` for web

Answer (score 0):

> Ok I got the problem, but I dont know why is it occuring

Like you already see in your code, **it is timezone issue**. `mktime` and `strtotime` functions are timezone/offset aware. Function `time()` on other hand is not influenced by timezone offset.

If you need `mktime()` that will always return GMT/UTC date, you can use [`gmmktime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmmktime.php).